# why it shows me "This site can't be reached" while hosing in server?

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded my laravel project in a server.
I have managed database and paths.
but it shows me this site can't be reached. Ip address couldn't be found
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Well, this sounds like the server is not reachable. This is most likely **not** a problem of Laravel. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase i have no idea what to do